# Angular Build creating files twice

Tags: angular

Im having an issue with a specific project Im basing on a template I purchased for an Administration Panel.

When I build the bundle (which I did just to see its size) Im getting the following files and sizes

[image]

This template had dozens of different components, which I got rid of, but I still have the following issues:

1. main is being created twice, so does runtime and polyfills. My "target" at tsconfig is "es2017",
2. I've deleted all "nested" routes, but I still have traces of Lazy Chunk files. Is there anywhere I can set "not" to use lazy load concept?

I believe the problem is at a tsconfig.json level but Im unable to identify it.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": false,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": false,
    "strictTemplates": false
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Danielle.

Comment: I see your styles file is pretty bit. Templates usually load tons of stuff. You may want to check which CSSs you are loading and if they are strictly necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the duplicated files issue, change:

```
"target": "es2017",
```

to

```
"target": "es5",
```

On your tsconfig.json